# UPDATE using INNER JOIN on SUBQUERY not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to UPDATE col1 in tableA taking data from tableD using this query (prototype):

```
UPDATE tableA
SET TableA.col1 = tableB.col1
FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT tableC.col1, id 
     FROM
         (SELECT 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tableD.col1 ORDER BY (tableD.someCol desc) AS "Row Number", 
              col1, id 
          FROM tableD) tableC
     WHERE [Row Number] = 1) tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id
WHERE 
    some_clause_on_tableA_and_tableB;
```

But unfortunately this doesn't works properly (incorrect updates), but if I explicitly store data of tableB in a #temp table and then try to update tableA from that #temp table then it works fine (prototype query):

```
SELECT * 
INTO #temp 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tableD.col1 ORDER BY (tableD.someCol desc) AS "Row Number", 
         col1, id 
     FROM tableD) tableC
WHERE
    [Row Number]=1;

UPDATE tableA
SET TableA.col1 = tableB.col1
FROM tableA 
INNER JOIN #temp tableB ON tableA.id = tableB.id
WHERE some_clause_on_tableA_and_tableB;
```

I am not sure why the later works but first doesn't. It seems that in first query the two nested subqueries (with row ranking) are not able to fetch correct data but I may be wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: None of them should really work as you are getting random row from tableD - there is no order to produce consistent row_number 1. You might also consider using `select top 1 col1 from tableD order by ?` as you only want one row.

Comment: Also, what do yo mean by "doesn't works properly"? It emits an error? Does not update? Updates to incorrect values? Update wrong records? Please post some sample data and expected result.

Comment: I had omitted that portion from the query to keep it simple fir viewers. I have added it to avoid this confusion. So the question remains same, why updating from suqquery isn't working while updating from #temp works just fine.

there is no error only the end result is incorrect, I mean that updates incorrect records.

Comment: I presume `[Row Number=1]` is a typo? and should be `[Row Number] = 1`

Comment: Also `tableB` doesn't return a field `id` how can the join work?

Comment: Does changing the first 2 lines beginning UPDATE and SET to a SELECT provide any more information to help you debug this problem?

Comment: +2 for pointing out typos and correction in the question!!!
@mouters
typo corrected, yes I missed putting the id column. Thanks for pointing it out.
I'll try to debug it as per your suggestion, tahks for your help!!!

Comment: So what did you discover? The result of inner joins sub-query should match the content of your temp table #temp.

Answer (score 2):

I get the feeling your probably missing the OVER clause making use of partition and order by keywords to group your tableA id's referenced in tableD.
So basically what I think you're trying to do is update each entry found in tableA with the first row found in tableD for each of tableA's id's.

Perhaps try something like this as your tableC subquery

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tableD.fk_to_tableA order by tableD.something
    ,col1 FROM tableD
```

EDIT following comment

For what its worth here's a simple example of the query you're trying and it works fine. In what way does this example differ from your problem?

```
declare @entity table (id int, latestEventId int)

declare @event table (id int, entityId int)

insert into @entity values (1, null), (2, null), (3, null), (4, null), (5, null)

insert into @event values (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 5), (6, 1), (7, 2), (8, 3), (9, 4), (10, 5), (11, 1), (12, 2), (13, 3), (14, 4), (15, 5)

update tableA
    set tableA.latestEventId = tableB.id
from 
    @entity tableA
inner join
(
    select
        * 
    from 
    (
        select 
            *,
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by e.entityId order by e.id desc)
        from
            @event e
    ) tableC
    where
        rn = 1
) tableB 
on tableB.entityId = tableA.id

-- expect the result of entity id's 1 to 5 with the values 11 to 15
select * from @entity
```

Comment: No, I just skipped it in the query to kep it simple!!! I have up-dated the query in question to overule that as a reason.

Comment: +1 for simplifying my question
@mouters Yeah this is very much similar what I am trying to do with my query, and I don't understand why inner join on subquery is not updating data correctly (wrong data is getting updated) while if I store subquery output in a #temp table and then perform inner join on that #temp tabel then data gets updated successfully :-(

Answer (score 0):

There must be something not covered by the examples. I mean, the two methods presented are equivalent to each other. But if your real query looks more complex, than that may somehow prevent you from seeing the real issue.

To help yourself to spot the issue sooner, you could simplify your query by getting rid of one level of nesting: the `[Row Number]=1` condition could be moved to the main query, like this:

```
UPDATE tableA
    SET TableA.col1 = tableB.col1
FROM tableA INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tableD.col1 ORDER BY (tableD.someCol desc) AS "Row Number",
        col1,
        id
    FROM tableD
) tableB
ON tableA.id = tableB.id
WHERE some_clause_on_tableA_and_tableB
  AND tableB.[Row Number] = 1;
```

Furthermore, since you are not really assigning `tableA` a new alias, you could omit it from the `FROM` clause of the UPDATE statement, like this:

```
UPDATE tableA
    SET TableA.col1 = tableB.col1
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tableD.col1 ORDER BY (tableD.someCol desc) AS "Row Number",
        col1,
        id
    FROM tableD
) tableB
ON tableA.id = tableB.id
WHERE some_clause_on_tableA_and_tableB
  AND tableB.[Row Number] = 1;
```

There's no implication to omitting the target table from the `FROM` clause, and yet the query itself might become a tiny bit cleaner and thus easier to spot a potential issue in.

Alternatively, as suggested by @mouters, you could rewrite the subselect as a common table expression (CTE) or, in fact, a series thereof if, for instance, `tableD` in reality is a subquery too. Consider this:

```
WITH tableB AS (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tableD.col1 ORDER BY (tableD.someCol desc) AS "Row Number",
        col1,
        id
    FROM tableD
)
UPDATE tableA
    SET TableA.col1 = tableB.col1
FROM tableA INNER JOIN tableB  /* or just: FROM tableB */
ON tableA.id = tableB.id
WHERE some_clause_on_tableA_and_tableB
  AND tableB.[Row Number] = 1;
```

Again, there's no implications to rewriting the subselect as a CTE (not in this particular case, since you are only referencing the CTE once), but this, in its own way, may (or may not) be instrumental in helping you to find the cause of the problem.

Comment: Or you could go with a CTE for the inner joins sub query.

Comment: Yes, good idea, a CTE instead of a "normal" subselect often makes things clearer.